# SQL Query Not working

Tags: sql

There are two tables named

```
Passenger (ID_psg, name)
Pass_in_trip (trip_no, date, ID_psg, place)
```

There can be several passengers bearing the same first name and surname (for example, Bruce Willis). My goal is to find the names of different passengers that ever travelled more than once occupying seats with the same number. It's exercise 63 given at [sql-ex.ru](http://sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref)

My Query at first try was

```
SELECT p.name
FROM pass_in_trip  pt LEFT JOIN passenger p
    ON pt.id_psg = p.id_psg
GROUP BY pt.id_psg, pt.place,p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I am unable to find out the reason why it did not return the desired result. I know it can be done using subquery but I want to know where I am going wrong. The place column represent the seat number. You can take sql-server as database. 
Desired result should look something like this

```
  name
--------
Bruce Willis        
Nikole Kidman       
Mullah Omar
```

Comment: Do you get a result when you remove the `group by`?

Comment: What do your data sets look like?  Or rather, what's your input/output expected to be?

Comment: Which field represents "seats".

Comment: Also - it looks like sql-ex.ru has terms in there that specifically ask you not to seek outside help or look for solutions elsewhere....

Comment: An inner join should be sufficient for this.

Comment: I've already solved the qus using subquery with IN operator. But I wanted to know why this query doesn't work.

Comment: Why u are using the Group by clause? Use distinct rather with select for different names.......

Comment: Also, as Dan Bracuk mentioned a normal join for this should be fine.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I am using `GROUP BY` clause to find how many times a person has flown with same seat number. And could you please elaborate more on your answer.

Comment: @Newd Yes, now I realize both normal `join` and `left join` would produce the same result. But still, that does not clear the doubt.

Comment: Try to remove the `GROUP BY` and the `HAVING` clause and see what results you get.  That should lead you to the answer, if it doesn't post the results of that query and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: @Newd Removing `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` will mean I won't be able to use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @BikashBehera You won't be leaving them out, you are only checking results before you try to add in the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the people who are in the pass_in_trip table more than once

```
SELECT p.name
FROM pass_in_trip  pt 
INNER JOIN passenger p
    ON pt.id_psg = p.id_psg
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will get you the people with the same name who have the same seat more than once. Note that this will include two people with different ids who have the same name.

```
SELECT p.name
FROM pass_in_trip  pt 
INNER JOIN passenger p
    ON pt.id_psg = p.id_psg
GROUP BY pt.place,p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will get you the individuals with different id_psgs who have the same seat (so two different people named Bruce Willis who each have used the same seat multiple times who show up in the results and you would see Brice Willis twice).

```
SELECT p.name
FROM pass_in_trip  pt 
INNER JOIN passenger p
    ON pt.id_psg = p.id_psg
GROUP BY pt.id_psg,pt.place,p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now when trying to debug code of this nature, it is always best to show all of the items in the group by in the select part of the query even if you intend to remove them later. Had you done this:

```
SELECT pt.id_psg,pt.place,p.name
FROM pass_in_trip  pt 
INNER JOIN passenger p
    ON pt.id_psg = p.id_psg
GROUP BY pt.id_psg,pt.place,p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then you would have seen why two Bruce Willis's show up and you would have known what the problem was.